# Submit form using ajax, and then disable button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My script is working, but there is one thing I can not solve.

```
  $(function () {
        $('#form_<?php echo $i; ?>' ).on('submit', function (e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'akcija_gaz_2l_insert.php',
            data: $('#form_<?php echo $i; ?>').serialize(),
            success: function () {
                //alert('form is submited');
            }
          });
          $("submit, input[type='submit']").click(function()
          {
          $(this).prop('disabled', true);
          $(this).css("color", "#15FF00");
          });
        });
      });
```

On first click it's submitting the form and on 2nd click it is disabling the button and changing the color to green. Can someone explain to me why it requires two clicks for this function? I want to do both on one click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,in your success function disable the button and change the button color like below

```
success: function(){
     $("#bttonID").attr("disabled", true);
     $("#bttonID").css("background","#15FF00");
},
```

Comment: no prob mate and don't forget to make it as write answer

Comment: dont understand what u mean by write answer? @shakir

Comment: their is write mark below the vote you have to click that to accept the answer
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

It requires two clicks because you are handling `click` event only when `submit` has happened. You should handle button change in the `success` function, or directly in the submitting function.

```
$(function () {
    $('#form_<?php echo $i; ?>' ).on('submit', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'akcija_gaz_2l_insert.php',
        data: $('#form_<?php echo $i; ?>').serialize(),
        success: function () {
            //alert('form is submited');
            $("submit, input[type='submit']").prop('disabled', true);
            $("submit, input[type='submit']").css("color", "#15FF00");
        }
      });
    });
  });
```

Comment: Thxs for explanation @hulothe